# regex matching syntax in google sheets not working

Tags: regex, google-sheets-api

I am trying to match cells in a range that contain the word `achievement` followed by a `.` then at least one other word. Can someone tell me why this returns NA instead of TRUE when cell A3 contains `achievement.blah`?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A3="achievement(.[[:alnum:]])*?")
```

which would include things like below as correct:

```
achievement.hello
achievement.hello.bye.hi
achievement.
achievement.hi9.bye33
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(regexmatch(A3,"achievement.[[:alnum:]]*"))
```

I don't think the `=` operator in this context accepts regex.

Comment: Just a note. There is no use having an optional `[[:alnum:]]*` at the end just for match sake. The only requirement of your regex is `achievement.`, which matches `achievements` as well.

Comment: yeah, I kinda thought about that. I just want to keep OP's original regex and make things work. Also, OP should change it to `\w*`, since he said he just want a **word**.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
achievement\.\S+
```

---

## Explanation:

```
/achievement\.\S+/

achievement matches the characters achievement literally (case sensitive)
\. matches the character . literally
\S+ match any non-white space character [^\r\n\t\f ]
    Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
```

---

## Demo:

https://regex101.com/r/aQ7mP1/1

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me when used within the regexmatch function in google sheets